# asp.net mvc - ajax.beginform post - viewdata lost?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

If I post a form using Ajax.BeginForm, do I have to set all the ViewData values again? That doesn't make sense, right? Why would ViewData slip?

Answer (score 0):

When you perform an AJAX call you usually want to update only a portion of the page by returning a partial view. So you only need to set ViewData used by this partial. By the way don't use ViewData, I would recommend you using view models and strongly typed views.